# multiple tables in database

Tags: android, database, client-server

I have to create an application a kind of client-server thing,both on android!!!

My client is moving on a direction and the GPS data of the route is stored in a database.

Now,I can have more than one client.The thing is that after the client connects to server,

this one has to read the data and store it in its database!

The GPS data that the client retrieves to server describes a route on the map.This data is

stored at the server for late proccessing.

NOW this is how I imagine the database:

First Tabel

_id      route

Second Tabel(the name is _id from the first tabel)

_id   longitude   latitude

Each time a client connects to the server(or the same client with different GPS data) I insert a row in the first tabel which describes the route (source destination) and the latitude and longitude describing that is stored in the second tabel.But when comes another client an connects I insert a new row in the first tabel and the data in another tabel,a third one similar with the second one.

Te  problem is that I don't know how to create spontanously new tabels.I've seen example with a number fixed of tables...

Has anyone any idea of how could I do that?????

Comment: what does that mean?How can I increase it?

Comment: ok.do u know how can I create a new table everytime a client connects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `user` table.  When a client connects/registers create a new `user` entry in the table and retain the `_id`.  Then supply it as column data when writing to the other tables.

eg

`_id user`

`_id route user_id`

`_id longitude latitude user_id`

where user_id is the _id of the user from the user table.

Comment: So you are telling me to create only three tables?...I was thinking to create a new table (_id longitude latitude user_id) for each client that regosters only that I don't know how to do it!